# How do I send mail from yahoo and others in android

Tags: java, android, jakarta-mail

I am trying to use Java mail. this works fine for gmail but when I trying to send through yahoo or hot mail it shows

```
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 553 From address not verified
```

I have used

```
mailHost = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com";
```

and `port = 465"`

can any body tell me how to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

here I Am sending the code

```
public MailSender(String userId, String password)
{
    this.userId = userId;
    this.password = password;

    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    properties.setProperty("mail.host", mailHost);
    properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");

    session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties, this);
}

protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
{
    return new PasswordAuthentication(userId, password);
}

public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body, String sender, String reciever) throws AddressException, MessagingException
{
    MimeMessage mimeMessage = new MimeMessage(session);
    DataHandler dataHandler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(body.getBytes(), "text/plain"));
    mimeMessage.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));
    mimeMessage.setSubject(subject);
    mimeMessage.setDataHandler(dataHandler);

    if(reciever.indexOf(",")>0)
    {
        mimeMessage.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(reciever));
    }
    else
    {
        mimeMessage.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(reciever));
    }
Transport.send(mimeMessage);    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The most likely reason for this error message is that you are required to login to the SMTP server before you will be permitted to send any messages through it. Alternatively, it may be because you are trying to send from a non-yahoo mail address, or one that does not exist.

Comment: @Mark:- I have alreay tried login with SMTP server and I have used my personal yahoo mail id. But error still persist. if possible please send me settings for SMTP. Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to send email *From* your yahoo address, or another one?

Comment: @Mark:- I am sending from my yahooID

Comment: If you could add your code to the question I can try and spot any errors, but without it, I'm not sure that there's any more help that I can offer.

Comment: @Mark:- I have pasted my code. If possible help me. Thanks for have concentration over this.

Comment: Does the `sender` argument to your `sendMail()` method match your full yahoo mail email address? If not, that's your problem - it must match.

Comment: @Mark:- yes That's is matched, I have checked that

Answer (score 1):

mailHost = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com";
and port =587
try this

Answer (score 1):

Try with these settings:

```
Server: smtp.mail.yahoo.com
Port: 465
Security: SSL
```